# How to install cygwin on an Arm64 Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cygwin, arm64

I have an HP Envy Arm64 notebook with a Qualcomm GPU, running Windows 10. I would like to install Cygwin and GCC on it, but I can't find a download that works. Is that at all possible ? Thanks,

Alberto.

I tried https://cygwin.com/install.html but none of the downloads work.

Comment: Based on this discussion (https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg157588.html) from the Cygwin mailing lists from July 2018, it appears that the 32-bit version of Cygwin may work. Corinna created a patch in the daily snapshot. There have been a couple releases since then, so if the patch worked, it should have been in one of those releases. 

Have you tried the 32-bit (x86) version?

Comment: Thanks Chris! The link is good, and the discussion is enlightening. In fact all I did was to manually create a C:\Windows\SysWOW64\drivers\etc directory before I installed the 32-bit version of cygwin, and so far no problem. If I bump into more problems I will try Corinna’s patch.